How to blend 2 NLA strips in a single track?
As shown in the image below, how can I blend 2 strips in one NLA track (Blender 4.2.3)? Is this a possible feature?
I know how to blend 2 strips that are on different tracks, but what I want to do is to compose the complete animation on a single track because when I export from Blender to fbx, then into Unity, Unity recognizes each track as a single AnimationClip to be used directly.


Hello you could bake the 2 NLA strips into one action: Select the object or armature, activate the NLA tracks that you want to merge, go into Object > Animation > click on Bake Action, it will create a brand new action in the Dope Sheet

@moonboots thanks... I read about baking the tracks, but this means it is still troublesome to edit after baking. If this is the only way to do it, I have to rethink about my workflow.
